# Fairplay encryption on enterprise iOS applications

Tags: ios, encryption, ipa, ios-enterprise

I am building an app that will be distributed with an enterprise license.  I am following these steps to build the application from xcode:

1. Choose Generic iOS Device.
2. Product -> Archive
3. Window -> Organizer -> Export -> Save for Enterprise Deployment

However when I generate an IPA in this fashion I don't think the binary is encrypted using apples fairplay.

I unzipped the IPA then ran this on the binary:

```
otool -arch armv7 -l thebinary | grep crypt
```

Which produced:

```
 cryptoff 15584
cryptsize 2364346
  cryptid 0
```

From some other sources, I believe 'cryptid 0' show the binary is not encrypted.

1. Is this the right way to check if the binary is encrypted?
2. Is there a way to use FairPlay to encrypt iOS Enterprise Applications?

Comment: Hi, Although it's very old question. Perhaps you did some investigation on this issue ? I'm seeking to understand exactly how is the binary encryption is made in terms of what algorithm being used, where is the key. thanks !

Answer (score 1):

> Is this the right way to check if the binary is encrypted?

Yes:

```
$ otool -arch armv7 -l thebinary | grep crypt

$ otool -arch arm64 -l thebinary | grep crypt
```

> Is there a way to use FairPlay to encrypt iOS Enterprise Applications?

No (AppStore submissions only)

Comment: Regarding how to trigger the encryption, so from what I understand, only Apple control the encryption when the app is being sent to appStore and the algo+key is also out of the developer scope. right ?