# Build Mach-o file as encrypted

Tags: macos, encryption, mach-o

I was wondering if it's possible to build a Mach-O file, or modify an existing one and then re-sign it so that the code sections will be encrypted.

I know that there's a flag called `cryptid` that represent the encryption type (by values `EncryptionInfo32/64 for load commands LC_ENCRYPTION_INFO_32/64 respectively)

However, I couldn't find anywhere in Xcode for how it's done.

EDIT : I'm well aware that it can be done in iOS, but my question relate to macOS, does the platform support this encryption feature in Mach-O file ?

EDIT2: So after reading the other question I understood that the whole encryption thing can only be done by appStore which is after the Mach-O file is already left the developer side. So in this case, Apple actually controlled the encryption/decryption algo+key and it's completely outside the developer hand, right ?
Also, since the Mach-O is being changed during the encryption, so who's in charge to re-sign the application ?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fairplay encryption on enterprise iOS applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38318284/fairplay-encryption-on-enterprise-ios-applications)

Comment: @Siguza, thanks for your help. I've edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot do this.

The only "supported" way of getting LC_ENCRYPTION_INFO added to your binary is by distributing through the iOS App Store. It is Apple who checks your binary for compliance with their rules, then encrypts the binary and re-signs it.

This is all backed by "FairPlay", Apple's proprietary DRM stack. Not much is known about it since the code is heavily obfuscated, but it is widely believed that it's built on features of Apple's custom hardware AES engine. Given this, it may or may not be possible to create an encryptor yourself, but it would require immense reverse engineering efforts to even find out.

Further, the entire FairPlay stack is only present on Apple's own chips. It is indeed available on M1 Macs, as you can install iOS apps off the shelf (so long as you leave SIP enabled), but it is not available at all on Intel Macs (the relevant kexts are `IOTextEncryptionFamily.kext` and `FairPlayIOKit.kext`, the latter of which is obfuscated).